# HBase KeyValue.maxSize cannot be disabled

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have added

```
 <property>
    <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
     <value>0</value>   
  </property>
```

in hbase-site.xml.

I changed `hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize` value from `hbase-0.94.27/docs/hbase-default.xml` and set it to `0`

```
<glossentry id="hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize">
    <glossterm>
         <varname>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</varname>
    </glossterm>
    <glossdef>
         <para>Default: <varname>0</varname></para>
   </glossdef>
</glossentry>
```

and change it from `hbase-0.94.27/src/main/resources/hbase-default.xml` and set it to `0`

```
 <property>
    <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
    <value>0</value>
 </property>
```

and also I set it on Java

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
          config.setInt("hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize", 0);
```

none of them disabled `keyvalue.maxsize`.  Is there another way to disable checking keyvalue size?

Comment: what is the reason you want to disable ?

Comment: On a side note, if you have 200MB values to put into HBase, I will
recommand you to write this in a file in HDFS (Almost 2 blocks!) and just
write the reference from this file into HBase....

Comment: The program parses Pdf documents and indexes their details, content etc. And also it converts pdf document to byte format, so I can both search it by keyword, title etc.. and download it whenever I want. Thats why I wanted to disable keyvalue, because program gives error when parsing some pdf documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you are on right place hbase-default.xml (not sure you have restarted after this setting applied)

If 0 is not working for you, can try anything less than zero as  described in description tag of screenshot.

[image]

***TIP 1: 
To print all HBase Configuration you can use this statement from caller, which will print all the configuration entries from different sources (either system properties or XML entries in unified way). To check whether your changes in setting were applied or not.***

```
HBaseConfiguration.create().writeXml(System.out);
```

***TIP 2: 
Master and Region Server configurations can also be dumped using
   http services. e.g. "http://master:16010/dump"***

Second thing, (which is precaution) Hbase is not recommended for too high data stoage for one cell, you may enter in to OOM.

```
For ex:  KeyValue size too large at org. apache. hadoop. hbase.
 client. hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize <value. (3896):
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds too large for this the
 size of 16MB, it will throw out of memory.
```

On a side note, if you have 200MB values to put into HBase, I will recommend you to write this in a file in HDFS (Almost 2 blocks!) and just write the reference from this file into HBase... or do some other way.

Comment: I have set it to both 0 and -1. After setting, I closed hbase master, zookeeper and regionserver then started again. I also set it to 200mb but it is like it doesnt accept any value.

Comment: print your Hbaseconfiguaration  like this to see what is actually happening inside LOG.info(configuration.toString())

Comment: were you able to debug by printing ?

Comment: it says `Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, hbase-default.xml, hbase-site.xml` I think it just shows the xml documents that uses

Comment: pls. forget about Log.info which was mentioned above. by mistake I have given... use HBaseConfiguration.create().writeXml(System.out); this will print all hbase configuration settings applied from different sources in unified way...

Comment: It showed configs that it uses but I cannot post it here. website gives error

Comment: <property><!--Loaded from hbase-default.xml--><name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name><value>10485760</value></property>

Comment: also I updated tips in my answer it self check that.

Comment: I also saw that but there is no way that it accepts value as `10485760`. I have four hbase-default.xml documents and I changed all keyvalue values to `-1`. How can it keep accepting default value?

Comment: as per above config your configuration setting was not applied now you have to get in to action. I gave the clarity of from where it was applied :-)